# Supplementary readings for Numerical Algorithms / Machine Learning books

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, book-recommendation

There are such books like:

> *Numerical Algorithms: Methods for Computer Vision, Machine Learning, and Graphics* by J. Solomon

Or:

> *Learning from Data* by Y. S. Abu-Mostafa at al.

But sometimes they require more math knowledge to understand theorems and solve exercises that I have. Could you recommend some Linear Algebra or Calculus books/courses that would help to go deeper, i.e. help to better understand theoretical foundations?

For example, I have found that the book *Introduction to Probability* by J. K. Blitzstein and J. Hwang is quite good thing for anyone who is not really good in probability theory to improve their skills. Is there something similar for Linear Algebra, Discrete Math, etc.?

**Update**

The main reason why I've decided to ask this specific question (because there are *a lot* of similar requests out there) is that it seems most of math books are too big/broad and explain everything at once. More like full-featured university courses. So I wonder if there is something more concise, more focused on numerical analysis, matrix operations, gradient methods, etc.